# Как убрать бесконечный редирект после установки сертификата?

Tags: nginx, ssl

Перебрал уже целую кучу мануалов, но ситуация не меняется, попадаю в цикличный редирект после установки SSL сертификата и настройки сервера nginx. Может кто указать, где ошибка:

```
 server {
listen 80;
server_name www.wherefilmed.org wherefilmed.org;
return 301 $scheme://wherefilmed.org$request_uri;
}
server {
listen 443 ssl default_server;
server_name www.wherefilmed.org wherefilmed.org;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wherefilmed.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wherefilmed.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
root /home/ugrobug/wherefilmed;
}

location / {
include proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}


}



server {
if ($host = www.wherefilmed.org) {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
server_name www.wherefilmed.org;
listen 80;
return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
if ($host = wherefilmed.org) {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
server_name wherefilmed.org;
listen 80;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Цикличный редирект откуда куда? Может, дело вообще не в nginx, а этот ваш gunicorn какие-то кривые редиректы шлёт?

Comment: До установки SSL все работало отлично, а изменения в Gunicorn не вносились. Получаю в браузере ошибку - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS,  если удаляю 4-ю строчку (return 301 $scheme://wherefilmed.org$request_uri;) то получаю стандарнтый ответ сервера nginx.

Comment: Ну вот, может, нужно внести изменения в gunicorn? Редиректы откуда куда? До gunicorn запросы вообще доходят? Что есть в access/error логах gunicorn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге сработала следующая настройка сервера.

```
    server {
   if ($host = wherefilmed.org) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name wherefilmed.org;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wherefilmed.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wherefilmed.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    server_name wherefilmed.org;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ugrobug/wherefilmed;
    }

     location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Уберите фрагент:

```
 server {
listen 80;
server_name www.wherefilmed.org wherefilmed.org;
return 301 $scheme://wherefilmed.org$request_uri;
}
```

И еще нет неоходиости в условии т.к. в этот блок server не попадет хост иной чем [www.wherefilmed.org](http://www.wherefilmed.org):

```
if ($host = www.wherefilmed.org) {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
server_name www.wherefilmed.org;
```

В другом блоке server аналогично не нужно условие. И не забудьте перечитать конфиг командой `nginx -s reload`

Comment: Данное решение не сработало, ошибка сохраняется

Comment: nginx -T выведет весь конфиг. Приложите его к вопросу и укажите при каком запрашиваемом url возникает редирект

Answer (score 0):

Вечер добрый! Пересоздайте сертификат letsencript используя cerbot,  с параметром  no redirect ,
Так как , с большой вероятностью в выбрали 1 параметр , а именно он и влияет на редирект (прописывая уже https в сертификат , за счёт чего и возникает циклическая переадресация ), копаться в настройках nginx нет смысла .

Comment: Попробовал отправил команду sudo certbot --nginx --no-redirect -d wherefilmed.org -d www.wherefilmed.org при вопросе переустановить или исправить  - выбрал переустановить. Перезагрузил все, почистил все куки - не сработало

Comment: А остальные условия удалили после  ?

Comment: if ($host = www.wherefilmed.org) {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
server_name www.wherefilmed.org;